# Display JSON data in chartjs

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I want to display thist data using chart.js. The idea is to visualizing the survey results. Primary user will be the team lead. I think about three line charts for all questionId. Chart will display date, person name and value from question.

```
getHistoricalData() {
return [
    {
        date: "2018-03-14T12:00:00Z",
        results: [
            {
                teamMemberId: "Abby",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 5
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 3
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "Bill",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "Castor",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 5
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 5
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "David",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 5
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 3
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "Eugenia",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 2
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 3
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date: "2018-03-07T12:00:00Z",
        results: [
            {
                teamMemberId: "Abby",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 5
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 3
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "Castor",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 5
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "David",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 4
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                teamMemberId: "Eugenia",
                questions: [
                    {
                        questionId: "1",
                        value: 3
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "2",
                        value: 3
                    },
                    {
                        questionId: "3",
                        value: 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
];
};
```

I don't know how to download this kind of data. Thank you in advance.

Krzysiek

Comment: does your data came from PHP ?

Comment: show us what you tried ? we are not here to do your job :D

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @satyampathak const CHART = document.getElementById('lineChart');

var lineChart = new Chart(CHART, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: Object.keys(data[results.teamMemberId]),
      datasets: [{
         label: 'My first dataset',
         fill: false,
         lineTension: 0,
         backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
         borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
         borderCapStyle: 'butt',
         borderDash: [],
         borderDashOffset: 0.0,
         borderJointStyle: 'miter',
         data: Object.values(data[results.questions.questionId])
      }]
   }
})

Comment: @RhalpDarrenCabrera nope, from js file

Comment: @progNewbie how to display data from getHistoricalData() into chart.js

Comment: You got two different dates. So how should the chart look like?

Comment: @progNewbie I thought about two charts - one for each date, with people and theirs values

Comment: But there are three different values for each person. How do you wanna visualize this? If you can clearly tell me, I can help you.

Comment: @progNewbie ok, maybe in this way:
the first graph will show eg value from questionId: "1" all people from one day, the second: value from questionId: "1" from the second day. And so with all values.

Comment: Then you will need way more then two charts.

Comment: @progNewbie yup, by i think the main problem is i dont know how to do any :) maybe if i find the way to do first, then will be easier to do it properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cpjazfyr/41/)

Try to read your data like this:

```
var dates = [];
var allTeamMember = [];

getHistoricalData().forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  dates.push(element.date);
  var teamMember = []
  element.results.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    var questions = [];
    element.questions.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        questions.push(element.value);
    });
    teamMember[element.teamMemberId] = questions;
  });
  allTeamMember.push(teamMember);
});
```

This gives you an array with all the dates. And also an array having an inner array for each date containing all teamMembers with their question values.

After having this data you can generate charts from it like this:

```
dates.forEach(function(element, index, array) {


$("#charts").append("<canvas id=\"chart-" + index + "\" width=\"400\" height=\"400\"></canvas>");
  var ctx = $("#chart-" + index);
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [1,2,3],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Datum: ' + dates[index],
            data: allTeamMember[index][getKeys(allTeamMember[index])[0]],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});


});

function getKeys(obj, filter) {
    var name,
        result = [];

    for (name in obj) {
        if ((!filter || filter.test(name)) && obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            result[result.length] = name;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

you would need to not always take index zero like I do but iterate over your teamMembers.

Hope that helps. Just try to do it yourself.